# Gravity Forms input field shifts down after clicking the submit button

Tags: css, wordpress, forms, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I have an inline gravity form setup to capture an email submission. The issue I'm having is every time the submit button is click the input field shifts down a little. I'm not quite sure where this is happening and if it can be fixed in the CSS.

You can view the action [here](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZphsDkZxhKCg30BMIFXxqLJiYPqvzgps1TV)

I've tried viewing the code in the console as I'm submitting the form but no luck in finding the issue.

Any thoughts and suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Phillip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by Gravity form's ajax loader (the spinner image).

How did you put the submit and input fields side to side? With a `display: flex` added to `.site-footer .gform_wrapper form`, it should work fine.

You can also style the ajax loader with CSS by using the selector `.gform_ajax_spinner`. Maybe a `display: inline` can fix it, or you can also hide it if that's easier.

Comment: Thank you Julia, this solved my issue. I was able to get the form inline by using gravity forms CSS class name gf_simple_horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following style to your `.gform_ajax_spinner`, and the issue will be fixed.

```
.gform_ajax_spinner {
    position: absolute;
}
```